# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties 'System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to update my project from .net 5 to 6. But not with the new DistinctBy with .net 6? Can someone explain to me why? Can you help me with this issue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; // Gray out
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; // Gray out
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.UI; // Gray out

public class UrlRoute
{

  public static string RegisterRoutes(string routes)
  {
    string MainUrl = routes;
    string result = "";
    if (MainUrl.Contains('\\')==true)
    {
      result = "CMS"
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like someone wrote a local version for use with .NET 5 (which doesn't have `DistinctBy()`). Now you've upgraded to .NET 6 (which *does* have `DistinctBy()`, you have two extension methods in scope with the same name, and thus the ambiguity.

Comment: What should I do? @Maathew Watson

Comment: The correct one is `System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctBy()`. Try searching your codebase to see if there's an extension method being defined for `DistinctBy()` somewhere. Or open a .NET5.0 project that uses `DistinctBy()` to see if you can see where it's coming from. .NET5.0 doesn't have it, so it can only compile if someone's added a custom implementation somewhere.

Comment: There would likely be a related `using <somenamepace>` at the top of the code file which might give you a clue. Investigate all the `using <somenamespace>` directives in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two extension methods with the same name and parameters available and the compiler does not know which one to use.

You can resolve this issue by removing one of the namespaces that contains the extension method if possible or by renaming the non Net extension method (if possible).